# Using UNION to add column value with criteria

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Basically I would like to add / combine the results from 2 table in a new table as below:

[image]

(add up values if colA & colB matches, origin value otherwise)

I tried coming up with below query (in access VBA) but it gives more than I want:

```
SELECT table1.A, table1.B, table1.C
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.A <> table2.A
UNION
SELECT table1.A, table1.B, table1.C+table2.C AS SUM
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.A = table2.A AND table1.B = table2.B
UNION
SELECT table2.A, table2.B, table2.C
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.A <> table2.A;
```

though it can be easily done with vlookup in excel; It's not as simple in access.  Is using UNION even correct?  Also I would like to stick with query, instead of using recordset where the origin data have 10000+ rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C)
FROM ( 
         SELECT A, B, C
         FROM Table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT A, B, C
         FROM Table2
     ) T
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY A, B
```

Comment: that was fast and perfect!  Thank you!  I understand the UNION ALL part and from, but how is selecting columns from UNION gives the result?  Also what does the T do?  (cannot accept answer till 10 minutes after posted)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out why it works now, thanks again

Comment: `UNION` will discard duplicated. `UNION ALL` keep duplicates and you can `SUM`. `T` is just an alias for the sub query so `FROM` treat it like a table

Comment: Appreciate your help!